# Read/save a file with Gremlin.net

Tags: c#, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, gremlinnet

I'm new in gremlin, But I have succed to have a janusgraph dockerized database, and to connect to it with Gremlin.Net 3.4.7 (thanks for the tutorials [PRACTICAL GREMLIN](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.pdf)  found on stackoverflow :D).
I try this :

```
        using (GremlinClient client = new GremlinClient(new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182)))
        {
            g = AnonymousTraversalSource.Traversal().WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(client));
            g.AddV("testV").Iterate();
            var vertex = g.V().ToList();
        }
```

The connexion is good, as the AddV() method succed.
Now I want to load a graphml file into the database, and extract the database content to another file.
But when i try to read :

```
        using (GremlinClient client = new GremlinClient(new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182)))
        {
            g = AnonymousTraversalSource.Traversal().WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(client));
            g.Io<Gremlin.Net.Structure.Vertex>(@"C:\Gremlin\toRead.graphml").Read().Iterate();
            var vertex = g.V().ToList();
        }
```

Its return : "ServerError: C:\Gremlin\toRead.graphml does not exist"
And the write :

```
        using (GremlinClient client = new GremlinClient(new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182)))
        {
            g = AnonymousTraversalSource.Traversal().WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(client));
            g.Io<Gremlin.Net.Structure.Vertex>(@"C:\Gremlin\extract.graphml").Write().Iterate();
            var vertex = g.V().ToList();
        }
```

Its return :
"ServerError: Could not detect the file format - specify the writer explicitly or rename file with a standard extension"

Have you ever meet this error ? can you see what I missed ?
Thanks for your time,

Parashift

Answer (score 1):

For the read (and write for that matter), note that the location `@"C:\Gremlin\toRead.graphml"` is relative to Gremlin Server not your local client. I assume that is the reason that your file is not found. On the write side, note that to use the syntax you are using, the file must end in `.xml` to be recognized as a GraphML file. If you must use the `.xml` file extension then you have to tell Gremlin that you want the GraphML format:

```
g.io('extract.graphml').with(IO.writer, IO.graphml).write()
```